# toString java? How can I get the return of a method to be used in toString?

Tags: java, if-statement, tostring

How can I get the output of eligibleForBonus() to be used in the toString method below.  I have used "this.isBonus" as a place holder but it doesn't work as isBonus is not a variable in the class.

```
public String eligibleForBonus(double salary){ 

    String isBonus;

    if (salary >= 40000) {
      isBonus = "is";
    } 
    else {
      isBonus = "is not";
    }
    return isBonus; 
    }

  }

@Override
public String toString() {
      return this.forename + " " + this.surname + " (" + this.id + "): " + this.companyPosition + " at " + this.salary + " and " + this.isBonus + " eligible for bonus.";

 }
```

Comment: I'd rather make `isBonus` to be `boolean` type.

Comment: @RohitJain I once saw code that had two fields: `hasSomeProperty` and `doesNotHaveSomeProperty` as booleans for the same property.

Comment: in toString method, run eligibleForBonus() method and use it in return method by storing value in variable

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Lol. That is terrible.

Comment: I hope you know, you cannot declare a method inside a method....

Comment: @JNL And where is he doing that?

Comment: @RohitJain There's no closing } for eligibleForBonus Method.

Comment: @JNL Sorry, I have added it now.

Comment: @OhHo72 Not a problem. Was just checking if you were aware of it or was a typo.

Answer (score 3):

As Rohit says, just call the method to get the return:

```
return this.forename + " " + this.surname + " (" + this.id + "): " + this.companyPosition + " at " + this.salary + " and " + this.eligibleForBonus(this.salary) + " eligible for bonus.";
```

A couple of opinions:

1. as Rohit suggests, returning a boolean (and then using a ternary operator to generate the text) is cleaner.
2. if the class has salary as a property, why do you have to pass it into the method?